# Galois groups: Why does |G(E/F)|=[E:F]?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

In case the notation I am using is not familiar to you, $G(E/F)$ is the Galois group of $E$ over $F$ and $[E:F]$ means the dimension of the vector space $E$ over the field $F$.

Theorem : Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $F[x]$ and suppose that $E$ is the splitting field for $f(x)$ over $F$. If $f(x)$ has no repeated roots, then
$|G(E/F)| = [E : F]$.

The book I am reading has a proof of the above theorem but it doesn't make much sense. I think it has a mistake. If anyone can explain it to me that would be great.
The proof goes like this:

Proof. We will use mathematical induction on the degree of $f(x)$. If the degree of $f(x)$ is 0 or 1, then E = F and there is nothing to show.

Assume that the result holds for all polynomials of degree k with $0 ≤ k < n$.

Let $p(x)$ be an irreducible factor of $f(x)$ of degree r. Since all of the roots of $p(x)$ are in E, we can choose one of these roots, say $α$, so that $F ⊂ F(α) ⊂ E$. If β is any other root of $p(x)$, then $F ⊂ F(β) ⊂ E$.

By Lemma 21.18*, there exists a unique isomorphism $σ : F(α) → F(β)$ for each such β that fixes F elementwise. Since E is a splitting field of $F(β)$, there are exactly r such isomorphisms. We can factor $p(x)$ in F (α) as $p(x)$ = $(x − α)p_1(x)$. The degrees of $p_1(x)$ and $q_1(x)$ are both less than r.

Since we know that E is the splitting field of $p_1(x)$ over $F(α)$, we can apply the induction hypothesis to conclude that
$|G(E/F (α))| = [E : F (α)]$.

Consequently, there are
$[E:F]=[E :F(α)][F(α):F]$
possible automorphisms of E that fix F , or $|G(E/F )| = [E : F ]$.

The parts that confuse me are when $q_1(x)$ is mentioned in the last line of the third last paragraph. It was not mentioned before and I don't know what it is. That was what I meant when I said there was a mistake. That part does not seem like a big problem. The main issue is that I do not understand why "Consequently, there are
$[E :F]=[E :F(α)][F(α):F]$ automorphisms"

The proof comes from "Abstract algebra theory and applications" by Thomas W.Judson.

If anyone has a different proof then that would be great too.

- If you were wondering, lemma 21.18 is: Let $φ : E → F$ be an isomorphism of fields. Let K be an extension field of E and $α ∈ K$ be algebraic over E with minimal polynomial $p(x)$. Suppose that L is an extension field of F such that β is root of the polynomial in $F [x]$ obtained from $p(x)$ under the image of $φ$. Then $φ$ extends to a unique isomorphism $ψ : E(α) → F(β)$ such that $ψ(α) = β$ and $ψ$ agrees with $φ$ on E.

Comment: Please provide a reference, preferably also a brief indication of where in the proof you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

To be as brief as possible assume that $f$ is irreducible and $\alpha$ is a root. Then the number of homomorphisms $F(\alpha) \rightarrow E$ is equal to $n=$ the degree of $f$, since $\alpha$ can be sent to any one of the other roots. Note also that $n=[F(\alpha):F]$. Now one can repeat the argument by factoring $f$ over $F(\alpha)$ and taking one of the factors, continuing in this way we end up with all maps $E\rightarrow E$.

Comment: How do you know there is only one homomorphism mapping α to each root?

Comment: I remember why now so don't bother answering my comment